# Ruby on rails Query related

Tags: ruby-on-rails, record

I have 2 Models

FOLDERS
:name
:parent_id

AUTHFOLDERS
:folder_id
:company_id
:user_id
:role #for sharing

```
class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authfolders
  has_many :companies, :through => :authfolders

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :authfolders

  validates :name, presence: true
end

class Authfolder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :folder
end
```

How can select "folders" where `Authfolders.company_id = x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join with your related table and then set your condition:

```
Folder.joins(:authfolders).where('authfolders.company_id = :company_id', company_id: x)
```